# Bad looking linear gradient at Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

I'm giving my  a linear gradient but in Firefox, even new versions, what I get is something like bars of solid color building the gradient. This is what's in my CSS:

```
 background-color: #d3d3d3;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(145,145,142,1) 0%, rgba(253,253,253,1) 99%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d3d3d3), to(#fcfcfc));
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d3d3d3',endColorstr='#fcfcfc');
 background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(211,211,211),rgb(253,253,253));
```

Comment: What do you mean _is something like bars of solid color building the gradient_?

Comment: Works perfect http://jsfiddle.net/acyNw/66/

Comment: Well it looks like this: http://d.pr/i/1fVU

Comment: Check your Firefox version or screen resolution, may be you have not installed display drivers !

Comment: Well it's not me, the client's computer displays stuff like this and my cross-browser testing software (browserstack) does the same...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients), it is most unlikely you are facing a version problem. Firefox, as usual, was the first to implement a standards-compliant (no prefix) CSS property (and it has already been 9 versions back).

Try removing the `background-repeat` property as it is mostly useless for gradients unless you've set a [background size](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts). If it solves, I'd recommend posting a bug report on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). Does it work well on IE10 and Chrome?

Comment: Yes, works without a problem in IE10 (and several older versions) and all Chrome versions I tested. Don't have an idea what's wrong with that code...

Comment: Try removing the percentage marks in your `linear-gradient`. That will mean "darker at 0%, lighter at 100%" which is really close to what you specified.

Comment: I tried everything you wrote, my body looks like this:


body {
  /* fallback */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168,168,168,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d3d3d3), to(#fcfcfc));
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d3d3d3', endColorstr='#fcfcfc');
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(211,211,211),rgb(253,253,253));
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


Still issues...

Comment: What Firefox version are you using?